# create a MessageQueue array from a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, msmq

Im sending messages to multiple queues which are held as pipe delimited in the app.config,
I want to loop through a Message[] array to do this, and have the queue name as a string[] array just now,

can anyone tell me how to do somethign along the lines of

```
private string[] sOutQueues;
sOutQueue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutQueues"];
sOutQueues = sOutQueue.Split(new char[] { '|' });
MessageQueue[] mQueues = sOutQueues
```

to get the MessageQueue array from the string array?

thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like `sOutQueues.Select(q => new MessageQueue(...)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var queueArray = sOutQueues.Select(s => new MessageQueue(s)).ToArray();
```